# low level version for bpy.ops.object.visual_transform_apply()

Tags: python, physics

I'm try to create lower level version for
*Object > Rigid Body > Apply Transformation*

`bpy.ops.object.visual_transform_apply()`

I`m not see any option to retrieve the objects transformation data from the rigged body simulation.

Any tips about that?